# How should I save hashtags Swift

Tags: ios, swift, hashtag

I am trying to save hashtags with an image to my server.

I am saving everything correctly, Image and the caption for the image.

Now I am trying to save the hashtag that are in the caption, I have though of one approach but I'm not sure.

So should I search through the caption text for prefix of "#" when uploading an image and save each hashtag individually and create a new row for each different hashtag in my "Hashtag" Table?

That seems to be the most basic way I guess, but if there was for example 20 hashtags wouldn't that do 20 queries? Now I don't this doing 20+ queries to upload 1 image would be a very good idea...

Now I am using MYSQL and PHP for my server, and I thought I could possibly do the search in my PHP file, but that would be the same result as the previous idea...

So now I am thinking if this would be possible: Just save everything normally, but when I tap on the hashtag within my app, I then search through all the captions of each image for the selected hastag and return that ppost?!

Not sure but if someone could give me there oppinion or reccomendation that would be great!

All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a db structure like this:

```
Table images
    - image_id (primary key)
    - filename
    - caption

Table hashtags
    - hashtag (primary key)

Table images_hashtags
    - image_id (foreign key on images.image_id)
    - hashtag (foreign key on hashtags.hashtag)
```

During upload, use a regex to find all hashtags in the caption and put them into an array.

Then, save all of them in hashtags table with only one query (use REPLACE, INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY); if hashtag already exist, can't be inserted again.

Then, insert the relation image-hashtag on images_hashtags table always with a single query.

It's a bit redundant approach, but you'll have more flexibility retrieving datas. If caption can be changed by user, you'll have to clear some rows during update. In my opinion, it's better to send the clean caption and manage hashtags logic on server side.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't sure fi I was going to get an answer! Any I have found a similar way to what I mentioned in my question that at the moment works smotthly and has no difference of speed if I add 20 hashtags or 0 hashtags. But I shall be looking back at it next week to double check everything. So I'll let you know but at the moment your answer seems the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can send you image as multipart data and array or hashtags as parameter by any key, for example:

```
"hashtags" : ["first", "second"]
```